# Best encoding to fit 10hours of 1080p in 30gb?

Tags: video, video-quality, encoding, mp4, h.264

I will be running a 10hour loop on a 1080p screen with only 30gb of storage.

The loop will be created from a variety of 1080p .mp4s that will need to be compressed. (for example, one video is 12mins long and is 1.5gb. Not ideal.) Quality is not paramount.

What is the most effective encoding to fit 10hours of 1080p into 30gb? The output needs to be .mp4.

I will be using a Mac and have Final Cut Pro, Handbrake and Compressor.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the maximum total bit rate that would fill the storage:

- 30GB ≈ 30,720 MB ≈ 245,760 Mb
- 10 hours = 600 minutes = 36,000 seconds
- 245,760 / 36,000 ≈ 6.83 Mb/s

You need to encode to a video bit rate less than that maximum to account for the audio and any overhead. Plus, you probably want to leave some space free on the storage. I'd say that 5 Mb/s is probably a safe bet. From there, you should try out different codecs and settings to see what gives you the quality you want at that bit rate.

Comment: Do you have any info on which codecs and how to choose the settings? I'm not adept at video encoding—I am not sure where to begin with testing different codec/settings @5Mbps.

Comment: H.264 should be a good starting point. I don't have any good suggestions for settings, since my background is on the broadcast side of things and the settings are vastly different for high bit rate than low bit rate. Depending on what kind of quality you are looking for, the default settings may be good enough. If it isn't, the best advice I can give is to try out changing one setting at a time on a short test clip.